# How to solve this TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' in python

Tags: python

I used all the technique mention online to solve below error
"TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'"
but failed.

here is my code

```
---
def checkfun()
    ---
    if (CheckBottomYCoVaring(length) == True):
    ---

def CheckBottomYCoVaring(length):
    result = False
    if (TempBotY > PrevbottomY[length]):
        if (TempBotY - PrevbottomY[length]) < 3:
            result = True
        else:
            result =  False
    else:
        if (PrevbottomY[length] - TempBotY) < 3:
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
    return result
```

Comment: that error is saying `TempBotY` is `None` at `if` statement eval time. where is it getting set?

Comment: Check the value of `TempBotY`: it is probably `None`

Comment: if (... = True) expr can be simplified to just if ...:

Comment: You can write this in one line:  `return abs(TempBotY - PrevbottomY[length]) < 3`.  Also remember you can fetch the last value in a list using `PrevbottomY[-1]`.  You shouldn't need to pass around the length, especially the length of a global.

Comment: if ..: result = T else result = F can be simplified to one line - will let you figure that out ;)

Comment: There's not enough relevant code to make a judgement here. One concern is how *length* is being used. Maybe it's just a badly named variable but if it's the length of the list (which I assume PrevBottomY to be) then you can expect IndexError

Answer (score 0):

The value of TempBotY was None

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).